# const(char)* cannot be modified

Tags: constants, d

Attempting to change IniFileName to null (to disable .ini saving) yields this error:

`Error: cannot modify const expression (*io).IniFilename`.

IniFilename is a const char*. It seems like the const is blocking my ability to change it.

I am using DerelictImgui, which is a dynamic binding to cimgui, a wrapper of ImGui.

Is there any way around this so that I can modify IniFilename?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The field in the DerelictImgui bindings is declared as `const char*   IniFilename;`, which is likely incorrect since it makes the whole field const instead of just the data; it should be `const(char)*   IniFilename;`. You may wish to file a bug.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo interesting! I probably will, but right now, DerelictImgui has some bugs that are much more limiting than just the ini one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply assign to null using

```
cast() (*io).IniFilename = null;
```

the `cast()` will just remove the modifiers from it so you are able to change it.

Comment: also (*io).IniFilename is the same as io.IniFilename in D